# Create list of Master-Objects for Detail-CustomObject and add Lookup to Detail

Tags: bulkification

I want to create a Lead, based on the data in my custom Object `ProductionOrganizer__c`. The ProductionOrganizer has a lookup-field `AttachedLeadId__c` where it can be linked with a lead.

Now when creating the leads in batch, my code looks something like this

```
public static List<Lead> createLeadsFromOrganizers(List<ProductionOrganizer__c> poList) 
{
    List<Lead> ls = new List<Lead>();

    for (ProductionOrganizer__c po : poList) {
        ls.add(new Lead (LastName=po.last_name__c,
                         FirstName=po.first_name__c,
                         Company=po.organization__c))
                         // some more stuff;
    }        

    insert ls;
    return ls;
}
```

Now the problem is: the Leads in `ls` obviously don't have a ID until I have inserted them. However, I need to match every Lead to its "source organizer" like this

```
po.AttachedLeadId__c = l.Id;
```

Where l is the specific Lead I created from this organizer. How do I solve this?

Comment: On the Lead you insert, add a custom field that is the ID of the ProductionOrganizer.  Populate that in your class above. Then, use a trigger (or flow) on Lead that, when created, locates the POs and updates their `attachedLeadID__c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, thanks to @cropredy for the hint.
My code now populates the lead "Description" field (as I can assure, that this will always be empty in this process) and uses it to loop over the Collection and fill the AttachedLeadIds directly in the same trigger-context.

```
public static List<Lead> bulkCreateLeadsFromOrganizers(Map<Id, ProductionOrganizer__c> pos) {

    List<Lead> ls = new List<Lead>();

    // create Leads from data in organizer
    for ( ProductionOrganizer__c po : pos.values()) {
        ls.add(createNewLeadFromOrganizer(po));
    }

    insert ls;

    // match inserted leads with organizers
    for (Lead l : ls) {
        If (pos.get(l.Description) != NULL) pos.get(l.Description).AttachedLeadId__c = l.Id;
    }

    // write lead ids into organizers
    update pos.values();

    return ls;
}

private static Lead createNewLeadFromOrganizer(ProductionOrganizer__c po) {

    Lead l = new Lead();

    // conditional copys
    if (String.isEmpty(po.organization__c)) l.Company = '[nicht vorhanden]'; else l.Company = po.organization__c;
    if (String.isEmpty(po.last_name__c)) l.LastName = '[nicht vorhanden]'; else l.LastName = po.last_name__c;

    // direct copy
    l.description = po.Id;
    l.FirstName = po.first_name__c;
    l.City = po.city__c;
    l.Street = po.street__c + ' ' + po.house_no__c;
    l.PostalCode = po.zip_code__c;
    l.Phone = po.phone_number__c;

    // static fields
    l.LeadSource = 'Organizer Account';

    return l;
}
```

I haven't had the opportunity to run my full tests yet, so I will update this post if something doesn't work as expected. Feel free to improve :).

/edit: All Tests passed. Single and bulk.